# WCF SOA naming conventions

Tags: wcf, naming-conventions, soa

I have an class library called ServiceLayer which acts as a repository for a ASP.NET MVC application This service layer has a references to a WCF Service called ProfileService which contains Profile methods to perform CRUD operations on a database etc.

I now need to allow mobile devices to communicate with my application so I have created another WCF Service called ProfileService. This service has a reference to the ServiceLayer class library and makes calls to it to undertake Profile operations.

Now this is quite confusing as I now have 2 ProfileServices. The first communicating with my database etc and exposing itself to my service layer. The second communicating with my service layer and exposing itself to mobile devices.

What is the best way to name your services in a SOA environment to avoid confusion of which type is which? especially when mapping between types.

I may also want to create another service which acts as an API to users of the system. What would I name this service ProfileAPI?? I know each ProfileService is in its own namespace but this doesnt help with readability when creating AutoMapperSettings or performing manual mapping.

So if anybody out there knows of a good way to name services in this environment it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [Service Facade](http://www.soapatterns.org/service_facade.php)

You would end up with a Facade, which is just a specialized interface into your real service.  You would define the different services as needed (mobile, users, database)

Comment: Thanks Nix, that is what my service layer is doing. It acts as a facade into the application. However since it references the ProfileService all DataMembers of the service ie UserRequest/UserResponse objects are visible in my Mobile  Device ProfileService where I am also using the Request/Response design.    pattern for my service and also have UserRequest/UserResponse objects.

Comment: Your service layer is accessing a ProfileService?  that doesn't seem right?  It should be the opposite?  A true facade should speak in common terms?  So all facades would leverage the existing service layer and really just serve as a translation from service layer->client.

Comment: Yeah my service layer makes calls across Wcf internally using net.tcp. I need this to be flexible as DB is on different server  Everything else references the service layer (or a representation of it at runtime using IoC). My Mobile device service then leverages the service layer for it's calls into the system.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498962/contract-first-soa-designing-business-domain-wcf ?